# Gradle java heap size error

Tags: java, gradle, java-8, heap-memory

Whenever i try to execute *any* gradle command on *any* project I get:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Java heap space
```

I tried changing java heap and executing gradle commands in a non-project context, but I get the same error. For example:

```
$ killall java
$ mkdir test
$ cd test 
$ export _JAVA_OPTIONS=-Xmx4096m
$ gradle wrapper
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx4096m

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Java heap space
```

Gradle version is `4.8`

```
$ java -version
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx4096m
java version "1.8.0_131"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)
```

**EDIT**
The problem seems to be gone after I rebooted the system. Can no longer reproduce

Comment: that, unfortunately does not say much, is there a stack trance may be?

Comment: @Eugene the `--stacktrace` option only logs generic java heap exception

Comment: well if can't reproduce, just delete your now question...

Comment: @Eugene I have posted all the available info, so it should not matter if I am able reproducing it after restart or not. I'm still interested to get an answer if someone has encountered a problem like that, it might serve me later on.